# Add options to R datable after the datatable is created

Tags: r, datatables, dt

I have an R script that gets a dataframe, performs some manipulations and eventually saves the dataframe as datatable for final visualization in my shiny app.
Depending on some user inputs, I would need to add to the datatable that has just been created some "options". To give you a concrete example, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
library(DT)
dt = datatable(iris)

# Add the options parameter using %>% operator
dt <- dt %>% 
  datatable(options = list(order = list(list(1, "desc"))))
```

However, it doesn't work. My datatable is more complex than just datatable(iris) but this should give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. Is there a way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("dtable"),
  checkboxInput("option", "Option")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  opts <- reactiveVal(list())
  
  observeEvent(input[["option"]], {
    req(input[["option"]])
    opts(list(order = list(list(1, "desc"))))
  })
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris, options = opts())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Stephane, I'm happy to see an answer for you, you're probably the best person who can answer this type of question. 
In reality, no, that's not what I meant. Basically, I already build standard datatables through a custom function. The function takes as input the dataframe, the dom type, some additional criteria like "show search box", "show paging", etc and it returns a datatable that already has some sort of embedded options.
My goal is to add to whatever option has been applied to that datable, a new option.

Comment: By the way, you may wonder, why all this? Because I realized today that all the columns defined as factor are not sorted taking into account factor values? I have quite big datatables and I spent a lot of time curating all the factor columns to eventually realize the sorting of those columns completely ignores factor values.